# Password Generator Ideas?

Tags: python, passwords

In Python, I want to write a password generator.

What inputs do you think I should place in the program that can help one create a good, strong password?

One sentence answers will be enough. I just want to begin a thought process.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Made my day XD

Answer (score 5):

In the spirit of the xkcd comic...

```
>>> import random
>>> def password_gen():
...   with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
...     words = [w.strip().lower() for w in f if w.strip().isalpha()]
...   while True:
...     yield ' '.join(random.sample(words, 4))
... 
>>> g = password_gen()
>>> next(g)
'mansion yodelling sumner coordination'
>>> next(g)
'proving velvetiest upload muggers'
>>> next(g)
'southey unfortunately longshoremen settings'
>>> next(g)
'inundated mules coevals vicious'
```

Comment: I now see Bernard Sumner trying to dance and yodel in a mansion, and this image will never leave me.

Comment: see, easy to remember, you could make it your passphrase  :P

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

random.choice(['password', 'password1'])
```

Comment: Where's the humor markup? ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, define what characters to choose from for your generated passwords, the constants defined in the [string module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) may be helpful here.  Then, use the [random module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) to pick a random selection of those characters, for example:

```
import string
import random

def random_password(alphabet=string.ascii_letters+string.digits, length=8):
    return ''.join(random.sample(alphabet, length))


>>> random_password()
'KwYGBtFb'
>>> random_password()
'CJOSx8tj'
>>> random_password()
'62BNJyX5'
```

Comment: So hard to remember those.  I guess you could write it on a sticky note and attach it to your computer.

Comment: I really doubt there is any way to generate passwords that are easy to remember, and hard for computers to guess.  Also, usually generated passwords are only used temporarily, for example as a part of a password reset mechanism.

Comment: I think this is a fine example for a temporarily lost password.  It's not a very good question.  Also, it's one that's been answered at least 10 different places on here.

Comment: @F.J: Of course there's a way to generate passwords that are easy to remember. Just get a corpus of words and pick random words from that. Much easier to remember than the above. But whatever system you have should have a mechanism to force people to change passwords from the random one sent out anyway, so it hardly matters.

Comment: And please don't use random. Use urandom. random.random may not be random enough. "<random.random> uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes." This is a cryptographic purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [uuid module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid4()
```

Comment: That's a pretty awful password, even for being random. However, it would make a good unique key for a password reset procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that randomly generating passwords is almost always a bad idea. Instead implement some sort of password reset algorithm, using long unique reset keys. For example generated with uuid as per Andbrews answer.

However, if you are somehow unable to implement a reset procedure, maybe because your client/boss simply refuses to listen to reason, then at least implement a function that means that once the user has received his new password, he has to change it to a new one, so that the password given to the user (on paper or by email, and hence available for everyone) must be changed to something only he/she knows.

Another thing to think about is to make sure the password is not possible to guess, even if you know the previous passwords sent out. Therefore, don't use the random module. I quote:

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces
>   53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying
>   implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister
>   is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in
>   existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable
>   for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic
>   purposes.

Instead the basis for the random password should be `os.urandom()`. However, it generates a sequence of binary bytes, so it has to be changed. The `binascii` module can be used for that. I'd suggest hexlify(), it makes the passwords that are easiest to type, no strange characters at all:

```
>>> import os
>>> import binascii

>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(10)).strip()
'7b2d0d5e40c18938bca9'
```